# Merge based on similar but not exact dates

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes. I would like to merge them only where the id is the same and the VisitDate is the same by no more that three days. Merging is simple but how can I specify the date range rather than exact date merge?

Here is a sample:

df1:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "Id"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(7L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-01-02", "2012-02-03", 
"2012-02-14", "2012-03-06", "2012-05-23", "2014-07-13", "VisitDate"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 3L), .Label = c("12", "2", "22", "23", "33", "43", "54", 
"Another column"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

df2:

```
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "Id"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-01-08", "2012-02-16", "2012-05-25", 
"2012-07-15", "VisitDate"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("22", "33", "43", "64", "Another column"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

The output should be:

```
Id      VisitDate.df1        col.2f1    VisitDate.df2    col.df2 
1       2014-07-13              23      2012-07-15       43
2       2012-05-23              33      2012-05-25       22
3       2012-02-14              12      2012-02-16       64
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So much better now. When dealing with dates this is extra important. Though it does seem that your column names are in the first row of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is not too large, you can simple join on `id` and then *filter* down to the rows that are off by no more than 3 days.

For example, under the `tidyverse` framework:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4), 
                     VisitDate = structure(c(15483, 16264, 15483, 15384, 15405, 15373, 15341), class = "Date"),
                     Column = c(2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3)), 
                .Names = c("Id", "VisitDate", "Column"), 
                row.names = 1:7, 
                class = "data.frame")

df2 = structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     VisitDate = structure(c(15536, 15485, 15386, 15347), class = "Date"), 
                     Column = c(3, 1, 4, 2)), 
                .Names = c("Id", "VisitDate", "Column"), 
                row.names = 1:4, 
                class = "data.frame")


df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = "Id", suffix = c(".df1", ".df2")) %>%
    filter(abs(VisitDate.df1 - VisitDate.df2) <= 3)
#>   Id VisitDate.df1 Column.df1 VisitDate.df2 Column.df2
#> 1  2    2012-05-23          5    2012-05-25          1
#> 2  3    2012-02-14          1    2012-02-16          4
```

An alternative approach is to *replicate* rows of your data, perhaps in `df1`. If you have the same ID occurring across multiple dates, this might be more efficient.

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(date = map(VisitDate, function(x){seq(x - 3, x + 3, by = 1)})) %>%
    unnest(date) %>%
    inner_join(df2, by = c("Id", "date" = "VisitDate"), suffix = c(".df1", ".df2"))
#>   Id  VisitDate Column.df1       date Column.df2
#> 1  2 2012-05-23          5 2012-05-25          1
#> 2  3 2012-02-14          1 2012-02-16          4
```