# How to merge two datasets based on similar but not exact time variable written in string. using R?

Tags: r, merge, strptime

I have two datasets I would like to merge that looks like this

```
df1
ID|date    |       time|
 1 04/06/21   "05:02:06"
 2 05/03/21   "04:12:11"
 3 02/02/20   "03:02:10"
 4 09/09/20   "09:12:14"
 5 02/02/21   "15:18:20" 
 6 04/04/21   "14:00:00"  

df2
2ID|date    |       time|
 1 04/06/21   "05:12:06"
 2 05/03/21   "04:08:11"
 3 02/02/20   "03:09:10"
 4 09/09/20   "09:12:14"
 5 02/02/21   "15:18:20" 
 6 04/04/21   "15:00:00"
```

Normally If I run a script based on exact match

```
df3 <- df2 %>% left_join(df1, by=c("incident_date","incident_time"))
```

I will get

```
ID|    date|time    |2ID
1  04/06/21 "05:02:06" 
2  05/03/21 "04:12:11"
3  02/02/20 "03:02:10"
4  09/09/20 "09:12:14" 4
5  02/02/21 "15:18:20" 5
6  12/14/22 "14:00:00"
```

Note I will only match two out of four however the remaining three out of four variables that are close in time I would like to match. I would like the script to do a give or take by 45 minutes which would end up looking like this

```
ID|    date|time    |2ID
1  04/06/21 "05:02:06" 1
2  05/03/21 "04:12:11" 2
3  02/02/20 "03:02:10" 3
4  09/09/20 "09:12:14" 4
5  02/02/21 "15:18:20" 5
6  12/14/22 "14:00:00"
```

I attempted to do something like this based off an earlier stack overflow question in regards to date, but it was not able to work. Would anyone know how to do this

Source: [Merge based on similar but not exact dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063188/merge-based-on-similar-but-not-exact-dates)

```
df3< - df1%>%
left_join(df2, by=c("incident_date"), suffix 
= c(".df1", ".df2")) %>%
filter(abs({strptime(df1$incident_time,format="%H:%M:%S")}.df1 - 
{strptime(df2$incident_time,format="%H:%M:%S")}.df2) <= strptime("00:45:00",format="%H:%M:%S))
```

Comment: What syntax is `{strptime(.)}.df1 - {strptime(.).}df2` from? I don't recognize that in an R context.

Comment: my time is in string format so i added strptime to temporarily process the string as a date time data type in order for the function to work. The way i did it might be wrong, thats why i need your help. Also it doesn't have to be written the way i wrote it, that was just a failed attempt  by me, but maybe i'm in the ball park?

Comment: I see what you think you were doing (by looking at the linked question), but it might be helpful to be explicit that it's untested *pseudocode*, since it cannot work in R. Regardless, see my answer, I think it gives you what you need. For the record, it is absolutely preferred to combine your `$date` and `$time` columns into a single column for several reasons, including `POSIXt` is *numeric*, allowing you to do "numerical difference" calculations that are meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `fuzzyjoin` package is best for this.

I'll add a `$tm` (`POSIXct`) column to both frames, since that is needed to get a clear "calculated difference" (in seconds).

```r
df1$tm <- as.POSIXct(paste(df1$date, df1$time), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df2$tm <- as.POSIXct(paste(df2$date, df2$time), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
fuzzyjoin::difference_left_join(df1, df2, by = "tm", max_dist = 45*60)
#   ID.x   date.x   time.x                tm.x ID.y   date.y   time.y                tm.y
# 1    1 04/06/21 05:02:06 0021-04-06 05:02:06    1 04/06/21 05:12:06 0021-04-06 05:12:06
# 2    2 05/03/21 04:12:11 0021-05-03 04:12:11    2 05/03/21 04:08:11 0021-05-03 04:08:11
# 3    3 02/02/20 03:02:10 0020-02-02 03:02:10    3 02/02/20 03:09:10 0020-02-02 03:09:10
# 4    4 09/09/20 09:12:14 0020-09-09 09:12:14    4 09/09/20 09:12:14 0020-09-09 09:12:14
# 5    5 02/02/21 15:18:20 0021-02-02 15:18:20    5 02/02/21 15:18:20 0021-02-02 15:18:20
# 6    6 04/04/21 14:00:00 0021-04-04 14:00:00   NA     <NA>     <NA>                <NA>
```

Obviously there's a bunch of name cleanup required, how about this:

```r
fuzzyjoin::difference_left_join(df1, df2[,c("ID","tm")], by = "tm", max_dist = 45*60) %>%
  select(ID = ID.x, date, time, ID2 = ID.y)
#   ID     date     time ID2
# 1  1 04/06/21 05:02:06   1
# 2  2 05/03/21 04:12:11   2
# 3  3 02/02/20 03:02:10   3
# 4  4 09/09/20 09:12:14   4
# 5  5 02/02/21 15:18:20   5
# 6  6 04/04/21 14:00:00  NA
```

Note: it is possible to find multiple matches (if multiple incidents are within 45 minutes), so you may need to add a grouped-filter:

```r
... %>%
  group_by(ID.x) %>%
  filter(which.min(abs(tm.x - tm.y)))
```

(needs to be done *before* my renaming and removal of the `tm.*` fields)

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, date = c("04/06/21", "05/03/21", "02/02/20", "09/09/20", "02/02/21", "04/04/21"), time = c("05:02:06", "04:12:11", "03:02:10", "09:12:14", "15:18:20", "14:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, date = c("04/06/21", "05/03/21", "02/02/20", "09/09/20", "02/02/21", "04/04/21"), time = c("05:12:06", "04:08:11", "03:09:10", "09:12:14", "15:18:20", "15:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to not concatenate date and time and have them separate? Also a way to not permanently process the string time as date time but only temporarily during the match? I basically want the date column to not merge on fuzzy join but actual join and the time column to merge on fuzzyjoin.

Comment: You want to limit to a *numeric* difference between two *strings*? ***No.*** You don't have to keep the `tm` fields, just use them to do the differencing and then delete them. (Nothing in my processing changed or broke either `$date` or `$time`.)

Comment: How about this ... I'll join all of both frames, not just `tm`, and you can work with all of the `.x`/`.y` columns.

Comment: In response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390378/merge-two-datasets-based-on-multiple-columns-but-make-time-column-flexible-withi#comment119119183_67390378 (since it's probably better to not clutter that question with this noise): changing the names to the new names here (`id`), this code works without error, and it works without changing the types of `date` and `time`.