# R merge close value

Tags: r, merge

My Question is similar to this, but I my problem is somehow easier, and so I hope for easier solutions. [How to merge two datasets based on similar but not exact time variable written in string. using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387991/how-to-merge-two-datasets-based-on-similar-but-not-exact-time-variable-written-i)

My dataframes look similar to this:

```
a <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                EG = c("CA", "EV", "EV", "TR"),
                year =c(2000, 2005, 2010, 2020), test = sample(4))

b <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                EG = c("CA", "EV", "EV", "TR"),
                test = sample(20),
                year = sample(2000:2019, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Now I would like to preform a left join like `merge(b, a, by=c("ID", "EG", "year"), all.x=TRUE)`. But I want: if  the year in a is not found in b, than the value of a shall matched to b where the year B is closesd (in conflict round off). That mean at the end all "ID", "EG", "year" columns  in the dataframe should have a test value from the closesd year B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr` version `>= 1.1.0`, we can use `join_by` with `closest`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(b, a, by = join_by(ID, EG, closest(year <= year)))
```

Comment: for me it gives the mistake: cound not find function "join_by" eventhough I have dplyr. dplyr:: join by gives 'join_by' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'. Can I just replace it by: c() ?

Comment: I mentioned `devel` version

Comment: sorry. I didnt recognize. I try again. First need to load devel version.